# Concatenate strings based on inner join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two DataFrames containing the same columns; an `id`, a `date` and a `str`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':      ['1', '2', '3', '4', '10'], 
                    'date':    ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
                    'str':     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':      ['1', '2', '3', '4', '12'], 
                    'date':    ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
                    'str':     ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Q']})
```

I would like to join these two datasets on the `id` and  `date` columns, and create a resulting column that is the concatenation of `str`:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id':      ['1',  '2',   '3',  '4', '10', '12'], 
                    'date':    ['4',  '5',   '6',  '7', '8',  '8'],
                    'str':     ['aA', 'bB', 'cC', 'dD', 'e', 'Q']})
```

I guess I can make an inner join and then concatenate the strings, but is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC `concat`+`groupby`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(['date','id']).str.sum().reset_index()
Out[9]: 
  date  id str
0    4   1  aA
1    5   2  bB
2    6   3  cC
3    7   4  dD
4    8  10   e
5    8  12   Q
```

And if we consider the efficiency using `sum()` base on level

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).set_index(['date','id']).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index()
Out[12]: 
  date  id str
0    4   1  aA
1    5   2  bB
2    6   3  cC
3    7   4  dD
4    8  10   e
5    8  12   Q
```

Comment: How to time this? This involves a groupby, so I think this is slower.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep , you are right involved groupby should be slow :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Update a method without groupby :-)

Comment: Sum with a level argument is the same as a groupby but definitely faster than explicit groupby + sum. Nice.

Comment: Why is this so slow in performance? A similar statement in R using `dplyr` would do this in 5-10 seconds at most

Comment: Did you time it ? Can you show the timing :-) (ps: I am also an R user , for me python is slightly faster than R dplyr)

Comment: Thanks, I will time both methods :-) @Wen How would your first suggestion (using `groupby`) change if the identifiers (`date` and `id`) were actual `int`, and not `str`?

Comment: @N08 when we groupby , no matter the dtype , it become the groupby key

Comment: @Wen Thanks! Is it possible to insert a space `" "` before summing the strings?

Comment: @N08 you can do join `df.groupby(['date','id']).str.apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x))`

Answer (score 6):

Using `radd`:

```
i = df1.set_index(['date', 'id'])
j = df2.set_index(['date', 'id'])

j['str'].radd(i['str'], fill_value='').reset_index()

  date  id str
0    4   1  aA
1    5   2  bB
2    6   3  cC
3    7   4  dD
4    8  10   e
5    8  12   Q
```

This should be pretty fast.